# string interpreted incorrectly in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, go

I have a string in golang as follows.

```
discount = "("+discount+"% off)"
```

when passed to html via angularjs it is displayed as follows
(10 %o(MISSING)ff)

Any idea why it is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in your HTML rendering process is passing the string through go's `fmt.Sprintf` or similar.  Try escaping the % by doubling it:

```
discount = "("+discount+"%% off)"
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/S_GEJXSfnD for a live example.

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks :). When passing the string to the angularjs, I was using fmt.Fprintf . So I am not sure whether that was responsible.

Comment: @tushR if you are not doing any formatting/substitution, you could use fmt.Fprint instead, and drop the %% escapes.

Comment: Iremoved the %% escape and changed to fmt.Fprintf and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to escape the string. Try to use this module: http://golang.org/pkg/html/

Comment: I tried to display the string in golang and there it is working fine. %10 off is getting printed. But when the string is passed to angularjs, there the string is interpreted incorrectly.